Generating functions of Wallis integrals
simple question, how would one go about proving that
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}^{}W_{n}x^{n}=\int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\frac{dt}{1-x\cos t}
$$
from this, it results with substituing $u= \tan(t/2)$ that
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}^{}W_{n}x^{n}=\int_{0}^{1}\frac{2dt}{1-x+u^2(1+x)}
$$
and noting that $f(-1)=1$ then for all $x$ in the open interval $]-1;1[$ we finish with:
$$
\sum_{n\ge 0}^{}W_{n}x^{n}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\arctan\left( \sqrt{\frac{1+x}{1-x}} \right)
$$
I'm probably just blind, but I have no clue as to how to get the first integral relation with the generating function of the Wallis integral.

Use $W_n = \int_{0}^{\frac\pi 2} \cos^n t \mathrm dt$ and the fact that $\sum_{n\ge 0} a^n = \frac1{1-a}$ for $a\in ]-1, 1[$. The only detail that you need to prove is the fact that you can interchange $\int$ and $\sum$ which is possible using Fubini.

Oh wow, I am in fact blind, it's been an hour since I've been stuck , thank you
